# Salesforce User object security hole

Tags: salesforce

I am working on an implementation in Salesforce for a customer which involves setting up partner module. We cannot setup access rights on User object standard fields based on profiles, and using partner login info, you can access all user info from Dataloader or Apex Explorer, which looks like a security hole in Salesforce.

Does anyone faced this issue before or has a workaround?

Comment: Hi Nitesh, I can see this is attracting close votes because SFDC development doesn't always involve coding. I'm proposing a Salesforce stack exchange site here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce Please follow and put an (abridged) version of your question there!

Comment: Also, when you say all user info, do you mean user info on their own record or on other user records?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, your concern is that you can access all of the User records using the Login information provided by your customer.

I agree that this is a security issue, but I don't believe it is Salesforce specific as much as the security practices of your customer.  If the user credentials won't need to access information via the data loader or Apex Explorer, then they should remove the "API Enabled" permission from the profile.  If the credentials should only have API Access they should turn on the "API Only User" permission on the profile.

What it comes down to is they need to restrict the "un-trusted" users to only the permissions and access levels that they need. I have found the profile permissions to be capable of meeting all of my security needs.